# How do I insert a code [table id=12 /] into WP post like a text

Tags: html, wordpress

I am writing a post about WP plugin TablePress. The plugin is active on my WP website. If you put a code [table id=1 /] into a post, the plugin shows the table on the front end.

How do I insert a code [table id=12 /] into my post as a text?

When I use `<code>&#91;table id=1 / &#93;</code>, WordPress changes automatically`[`to`[`and`]`to`]`and the table is loaded on the front end. But I want to post the code, not the table.`` doesn't work either.

Wordpress changes `&#91;` to `[` when I switch from Visual Editor to HTML Editor(.

How do I fix it? Please, help.

[Back End Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/svP3C.png)

[Front End Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gzwMM.png)

Comment: share screenshots of both admin panel and front end

Comment: Ready, please, have a look. There should be no tables on the front end, just a code of the table.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try any of these?

[wordpress](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/33960/how-do-i-escape-a-in-a-short-code)

I can't reproduce your problem... using [ and ] stop my shortcodes from compiling

Comment: Thanks. Do you have TablePress installed? WordPress auto change '&#91;' to '['. That's why shortcode is being compiled(((...